# how to build a custom keras layer witth unkown input shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a custom ConvLSTM layer in keras using the following code but it didn't work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import InputSpec, Layer 

class Padding2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, padding = (1,1), **kwargs):
        self.padding = tuple(padding)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim = 4)]
        super(Padding2D,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, s):
        return (s[0], s[1] + 2*self.padding[0], s[2] + 2*self.padding[1], s[3])

    def call(self, x):
        w_pad, h_pad = self.padding 
        return tf.pad(x, [[0,0], [h_pad,h_pad],[w_pad,w_pad],[0,0]])

class ConvLSTM(Layer):
    def __init__(self, out_channels, kernel_size=5, forget_bias=1.0, padding=0):
        super(ConvLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        self.forget_bias = forget_bias
        self.states = None

    def call(self, inputs):
        if self.states is None:
            #inputs.shape : [Batch, Height, Width, Channel]
            self.states = (tf.zeros([inputs.shape[0], inputs.shape[1], inputs.shape[2], self.out_channels]),
                  tf.zeros([inputs.shape[0], inputs.shape[1], inputs.shape[2]], self.out_channels))

        c, h = self.states
        if not (len(c.shape) == 4 and len(h.shape) == 4 and len(inputs.shape) == 4):
            raise TypeError("Incorrect shapes")

        inputs_h = tf.concat((inputs, h), axis=3)
        padded_inputs_h = Padding2D(padding = (padding,padding))(inputs_h)
        i_j_f_o = Conv2D( 4 * out_channels, kernel_size, strides=1)(padded_inputs_h)
        i = i_j_f_o[:,:,:,: self.out_channels]
        j = i_j_f_o[:,:,:,self.out_channels : 2*self.out_channels]
        f= i_j_f_o[:,:,:, 2*self.out_channels : 3*self.out_channels]
        o = i_j_f_o[:,:,:, 3*self.out_channels :]
        # i, j, f, o = torch.split(i_j_f_o,  self.out_channels, dim=3)

        new_c = c * sigmoid(f + self.forget_bias) + sigmoid(i) * tanh(j)
        new_h = tanh(new_c) * sigmoid(o)
        self.states = (new_c, new_h)

        return new_h

input0 = tf.keras.Input(shape= (2,2,1))
x = ConvLSTM(out_channels= 1)(input0)
model = tf.keras.Model(input0,x)
print(model(tf.ones((1,2,2,1))))
```

**Error output**

```
----> x = ConvLSTM(out_channels= 1)(input0)
TypeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-1-2e11c0026581>:28 call  *
        self.states = (tf.zeros([inputs.shape[0], inputs.shape[1], inputs.shape[2], self.out_channels]),
TypeError: Expected int32, got None of type 'NoneType' instead.
```

I think the error occurs because the model don't know in advance the value of the batch_size dimension (inputs.shape[0]) which is set to None when the model is built (before execution) but I need to make the model figure out by itself the batch size dimension during execution time (and ignore it in building time). Can anyone help please ?

Comment: Using implicit dimensions is typically used when setting up the graph (i.e., in non-eager mode). Have you tried using `@tf.function` to wrap your `call` method? Or using `disable_eager_execution()`?

Comment: Yes I tested it and didn't work

Comment: Maybe you could do it in a different way that does not explicitly require the shape values:   
"c = tf.tile(tf.zeros_like(inputs[:, :, :, 0]), [1, 1, 1, self.out_channels])". I am not quite sure whether inputs[:, :, :, 0] reduces the number of dimensions, if this is the case you would need to replace it by "tf.expand_dims(inputs[:, :, :, 0], axis=-1)"

Comment: @MarcFelix Your solution worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

By following the suggestion given by Marc above in the comments, this code solved the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import InputSpec, Layer, Conv2D 
from tensorflow.keras.activations import sigmoid, tanh

class Padding2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, padding = (1,1), **kwargs):
        self.padding = tuple(padding)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim = 4)]
        super(Padding2D,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, s):
        return (s[0], s[1] + 2*self.padding[0], s[2] + 2*self.padding[1], s[3])

    def call(self, x):
        w_pad, h_pad = self.padding 
        return tf.pad(x, [[0,0], [h_pad,h_pad],[w_pad,w_pad],[0,0]])

class ConvLSTM(Layer):
    def __init__(self, out_channels, kernel_size=1, forget_bias=1.0, padding=0):
        super(ConvLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.forget_bias = forget_bias
        self.padding=padding
        self.states = None

    def call(self, inputs):
        if self.states is None:
            #inputs.shape : [Batch, Height, Width, Channel]
            self.states = (  tf.zeros_like(tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(inputs[:,:,:,0], axis=-1), (1,1,1,self.out_channels))),
               tf.zeros_like(tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(inputs[:,:,:,0], axis=-1), (1,1,1,self.out_channels))))
    
        c, h = self.states
        if not (len(c.shape) == 4 and len(h.shape) == 4 and len(inputs.shape) == 4):
            raise TypeError("Incorrect shapes")

        inputs_h = tf.concat((inputs, h), axis=3)
        padded_inputs_h = Padding2D(padding = (self.padding,self.padding))(inputs_h)
        i_j_f_o = Conv2D( 4 * self.out_channels, self.kernel_size, strides=1)(padded_inputs_h)
        i = i_j_f_o[:,:,:,: self.out_channels]
        j = i_j_f_o[:,:,:,self.out_channels : 2*self.out_channels]
        f= i_j_f_o[:,:,:, 2*self.out_channels : 3*self.out_channels]
        o = i_j_f_o[:,:,:, 3*self.out_channels :]

        new_c = c * sigmoid(f + self.forget_bias) + sigmoid(i) * tanh(j)
        new_h = tanh(new_c) * sigmoid(o)
        self.states = (new_c, new_h)

        return new_h
```

I also found another alternative to solve the problem by providing the batch size and input shape when initializing the layer.
The code is given below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import InputSpec, Layer, Conv2D 
from tensorflow.keras.activations import sigmoid, tanh

class Padding2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, padding = (1,1), **kwargs):
        self.padding = tuple(padding)
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim = 4)]
        super(Padding2D,self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def compute_output_shape(self, s):
        return (s[0], s[1] + 2*self.padding[0], s[2] + 2*self.padding[1], s[3])

    def call(self, x):
        w_pad, h_pad = self.padding 
        return tf.pad(x, [[0,0], [h_pad,h_pad],[w_pad,w_pad],[0,0]])

class ConvLSTM(Layer):
    def __init__(self,batch_size, input_shape, out_channels, kernel_size=1, forget_bias=1.0, padding=0):
        super(ConvLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.forget_bias = forget_bias
        self.shape = input_shape
        self.padding=padding
        self.states = None
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def build(self, input_shape):
        if self.states is None:
            #input_shape : [Height, Width, Channel]  
            self.states = (tf.zeros([self.batch_size]+ self.shape[:-1] + [self.out_channels]),
               tf.zeros([self.batch_size]+ self.shape[:-1] + [self.out_channels]))
        super(ConvLSTM,self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        c, h = self.states
        if not (len(c.shape) == 4 and len(h.shape) == 4 and len(inputs.shape) == 4):
            raise TypeError("Incorrect shapes")

        inputs_h = tf.concat((inputs, h), axis=3)
        padded_inputs_h = Padding2D(padding = (self.padding,self.padding))(inputs_h)
        i_j_f_o = Conv2D( 4 * self.out_channels, self.kernel_size, strides=1)(padded_inputs_h)
        i,j,f,o = tf.split(i_j_f_o, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=3)

        new_c = c * sigmoid(f + self.forget_bias) + sigmoid(i) * tanh(j)
        new_h = tanh(new_c) * sigmoid(o)
        self.states = (new_c, new_h)

        return new_h
```

Yet, even if these implementations solved the question asked in this post, there still remain a problem in both implementations related to how I update lstm cell state (line self.states = (new_c, new_h) """Last line in ConvLSTM class"""") but since the problem is different I opened this issue in a different [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69568057/how-to-construct-custom-convlstm-layer-in-keras)